# Git Auto Commit Daily

Tags: linux, git, git-commit

Could I do take commit my changes in a directory by a daily routine? Say, In every 12 AM at early morning, It should commit all the changes in that directory automatically? Is it possible in git? I get some answers for auto commit for every changes. But I want it for daily once commit.

Comment: You might want to Thing a little more about what an SCM can do for you! Committing a random state into your repository is almost never what you want. A better choice would be every time your Project compiles (and all automated tests are passing). However, this should *always* be an explicit decision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you simply want to commit ALL changes every morning at 12 AM, you can do this using a cronjob.

Assuming that you are using a linux distribution with bash, you can write a bash script that does the commit

```
#!/bin/bash
cd <git directory> && git add -A && git commit * --allow-empty-message -m ''
```

Then you can place this cron job in /etc/cron.d/

```
0 0 * * * <username> /bin/bash <script location>
```

If you intend to run this as your own user only then you can instead add it to your personal crontab interactively by running

```
crontab -e
```

Comment: downvoted because while this solution is technically correct it does not address the potential missuse of the SCM.

Comment: His usage makes sense if he intends to use git to track certain results, it doesn't always have to be code.

Comment: I disagree. a SCM is not a backup tool.

Comment: It is not for "backup". For example it could be used to track jupyter notebook results that are ran daily with a cronjob. Git diff would be able to give a clear difference between the daily output.

Comment: Downvoted because `git commit` without `-m` starts the configured editor and waits for it to exit. It doesn't work when it is launched by the cron daemon. `git commit *` is even worse because the `*` wildcard is expanded by the shell to the list of files and directories in the current directory. It generates a command line you don't control and that also won't work (unless there is a file named `-m` in the project).

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake there because git commit * would require user input.

Comment: Also, `git add *` does not add the hidden files (whose names start with `.`). The correct way to add to the index all the new, modified and removed files is [`git add -A`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add--A)

Comment: *"It is not for "backup"."* You know the OP and her initial problem? I don't. / *"it could be used to track jupyter notebook results"* You also could place the daily Reports in separate Folders which would alow to clean up from time to time...

Comment: I meant "Tracking certain results is not for backup purpose".

Sure I don't know the OP initial problem, I was just pointing out that daily git auto commit could be legit for purposes other than source code tracking.

Comment: Using git for a back up is perfectly fine in cases where you want to back up say diary or org files - it's a chronological backup. You are backing up the "the timeline".

Comment: A daily commit after hours might make sense for some shops. Especially where automated testing is not done/possible. It is easy to include a standard commit message that clearly spells out that this is an automated daily commit and may have incomplete functionality.

Comment: `git -C $HOME/repository/path/ add --all && git -C $HOME/repository/path/ commit --all --allow-empty-message --message=''` may be preferred instead. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/748348/how-to-deploy-an-automated-version-control-system-with-git